# Undefined variables, value == false versus !value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a very simple piece of code written in Javascript, could you help me please?

Here's what I think I have understand so far about javascript and variables:

- An undefined value is evaluated to false in a boolean operation
- By using a == operator in a comparation, you're asking if two values are comparable regardless of their types

I found an exercise file in a online course and I tried to do it, but I didn't got the same result expected in the lesson; the main problem was that I was comparing the value through a "if value == false { ... }" while the solution was using a "if !value { ... }"

So I decided to write a very short code in order to try it by myself, but I'm getting mixed results. Here in the example below I would expect this JS code to generate two identical alerts ("foo is equal to false"), but instead the first if statement returns "foo IS NOT equal to false" while the second if returns (as expected) "foo is equal to false".

This is what I written:

```
var foo = undefined;

if (foo == false) {
  alert("foo is equal to false");
} else {
  alert("foo is not equal to false"); // Javascript executes this row
}

if (!foo) {
  alert("foo is equal to false");  // Javascript executes this row
} else {
  alert("foo is not equal to false");
}
```

AFAIK the two IFs should do the same work, and infact when I tried it by replacing in the first line the value "var foo = undefined;" with "var foo = 0;" it worked as expected, and 0 is another value that should be evaluated to false, or at least this is what I remember.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thats because is not equal to `false`. However undefined is falsey so `!undefined` -> true

Comment: Which is the difference between being equal to false and being "falsey" ?

Comment: if equal then `x == false` if falsey then `!x == true`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The  `==` algorithm *([Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3))* isn't something where you can simply assume an outcome unless you know the algorithm. You need to know the details of how it works.

For example, `null` and `undefined` are a special case. They do not do any type conversion other than to be considered equal to each other.

Otherwise there's typically a type conversion that tries to reduce both operands to a common type. This often ends up being a *toNumber* conversion.

That's why:

- `null == undefined; // true`
- `null == 0; // false`
- `+null == '0' // true`

So if you know how the algorithm works, you know that `undefined` never equals anything except for `undefined` and `null`, but other types that are not strictly equal may be coerced down to types that are equal.

So doing `if(!x)` vs `if(x==false)` are entirely different tests.

- `if(!x)` performs *toBoolean* conversion.
- `if(x == false)` uses a complex algorithm to decide the proper conversion.

So with...

```
if(x == false)
```

...if `x` is `undefined`, it is determined to not be equal to `false`, yet if `x` is `0` or even `"0"`, it will be considered equal to `false`.

- `0 == false; // true`
- `"0" == false; // true`

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'm starting to understand my mistake

Comment: Is there any where to find what's its complex algorithm or how does it work in details? Would you explain?

Comment: @mrReiha: This is all detailed in the ECMAScript language specification. Here's a link to the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3)

Answer (score 13):

undefined does not equal to false, but when you are trying to evaulate:

```
if (undefined)
```

the whole expression is always false

more info: http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls:_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN

Answer (score 7):

Truth and equivalence with `true` are two different things in JavaScript.

The `if (...)` executes the first statement if the `...` is "**truthy**", not when they are "equal" to any other particular value, so your second conditional should look like

```
if (!foo) {
  alert("foo is falsy");  // Javascript executes this row
} else {
  alert("foo is truthy");
}
```

There are quite a few "falsy" values in JavaScript: `NaN`, `""`, `0`, `-0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`.  All other values are `truthy`.

The `!` operator returns `false` for any truthy value and `true` for any `falsy` value, so `!x` is the same as `(x ? false : true)` for all `x`.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule I find that the positive outcome is easier to parse, almost as if `if(!foo)` is a double-negative, so I'd tend to turn it around:

```
if (foo) {
  alert("foo is something or boolean true");
} else {
  alert("foo is null, undefined or boolean false");
}
```

In particular both `undefined` and `null` are not true or false, but javascript can handle a kind of shorthand because it's dynamic.

Really the statement above is something like:

```
if (foo != null && (foo.constructor !== Boolean || foo == true)) {
  alert("foo is something or boolean true");
} else {
  alert("foo is null, undefined or boolean false");
}
```

You're checking first that the variable has been defined and then that if it is boolean that it's true.

Meanwhile your false statement is checking something different:

```
if (foo == false) {
  alert("foo is populated with the boolean false");
} else {
  alert("foo is true, something else or null");
}
```

Comment: `"foo is null, undefined or boolean false"` or +/-0 or NaN or the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let myVar = undefined
console.log(myVar)
console.log(!!myVar)

myVar = true
console.log(!!myVar)
```