# How to conditionally show span in AngularJS template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following list of objects:

```
[
    { "name" : "foo", "description" : "description of foo..." },
    { "name" : "bar", "description" : "description of bar..." },
    { "name" : "baz" },
    ...
]
```

All objects have a `name`, but some have an associated `description`, and the rest do not.

I use the following template with an `input` field connected to a typeahead, to show each matching object:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
    <a style="text-align: left;">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; display:block;">{{match.model.name}}</span> 
        <span ng-show="typeof({{match.model.description}}) !== 'undefined'">{{match.model.description}}</span>
    </a>
</script>
```

I would like the template to show the `description` only when its value is defined, but my use of `ng-show` returns parsing errors.

How should I use `ng-show` or another directive to render the `description`, only when this object key (and its value) is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
    <a style="text-align: left;">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; display:block;">{{match.model.name}}</span> 
        <span ng-show="match.model.description">{{match.model.description}}</span>
    </a>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; this worked correctly for me.

Answer (score 3):

You should only check for variable value, that's enough

```
<span ng-if="match.model.description">{{match.model.description}}</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The `ng-if` directive did not work for me, although `ng-show` did. I am using AngularJS 1.4.7.

Comment: @AlexReynolds `ng-if` should also work.. `ng-if`/`ng-show` both are similar, but difference, `ng-show` applies `display:none` css based on expression, & `ng-if` does add remove that element based on expression value.

Answer (score 1):

Just use it without `typeof` - and don't use the curly brackets, as `ng-show` is already relative to your scope. In JavaScript, `if(undefined)` has the same outcome as `if(false)` (see [Undefined variables, value == false versus !value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730792/undefined-variables-value-false-versus-value))

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="my-template.html">
  <a style="text-align: left;">
    <span style="font-size: 18px; display:block;">{{match.model.name}}</span> 
    <span ng-show="match.model.description">{{match.model.description}} </span>
  </a>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-if="match.model.description"` instead of `ng-show`. ngIf differs from ngShow in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM rather than changing its visibility via the display css property.