# Is "ssl : true" a valid option to connect to a mysql server using ssl

Tags: mysql, node.js, ssl

I currently use the `mysql` module with the following code to connect to my server:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'db1.domain.tld',
  user : 'username',
  password : 'xxxxxx',
  ssl : true
});
```

And this works without any problems, but out of the documentation it is not clear that this is even valid. There they write:

> **SSL options**
>   The ssl option in the connection options takes a **string or an object**. When given a string, it uses one of the predefined SSL profiles included.

So base on that description `ssl : true` would not be valid. So my question is, if this is a valid option, and why?

Comment: Check the code. Maybe the documentation isn't complete.

Comment: @tadman I was already searching in the source code, but I was not able to find reliable argument until now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Investigating the source code the behaviour of

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'db1.domain.tld',
  user : 'username',
  password : 'xxxxxx',
  ssl : true
});
```

Will be equal to write:

```js
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'db1.domain.tld',
  user : 'username',
  password : 'xxxxxx',
  ssl : {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

The reason for this is because of this part of the code in `ConnectionConfig.js`:

```
if (this.ssl) {
  // Default rejectUnauthorized to true
  this.ssl.rejectUnauthorized = this.ssl.rejectUnauthorized !== false;
}
```

Because `this.ssl` holds a boolean in the given case, the `this.ssl.rejectUnauthorized = ...` does nothing and `this.ssl.rejectUnauthorized` will be `undefined` after that if.

Because `undefined` is a falsy value, it will behave the same way as if `rejectUnauthorized` is set to `false`. So it would use `ssl` but it would not reject an invalid certificate.

As of that setting `ssl` to a boolean is not valid, or at least will result in an unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I think there is a mistake on the current comment: I'd say the equivalent code should be `ssl : { rejectUnauthorized: undefined }` instead. Since if `ssl = true`, then `ssl.rejectUnauthorized` is `undefined`, which is _falsy_ but **not** `false`.  The expression `this.ssl.rejectUnauthorized !== false` will be `true` (and not _false_, as it's currently stated in the current comment). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8730864/18170108) for further explanation.